# Is there a digital speaker?

Tags: speakers, digital

I wonder if there is a digital speaker can be plugged into a digital output on a sound interface

Comment: "digital output" is very broad. Could you clarify?

Comment: Genelec DSP series 2840A

Answer (score 1):

There are powered speaker products with digital (AES, SPDIF, TOSLINK, etc.) inputs. From cheap $20 plastic "computer speakers" up through professional monitor speakers that cost $1000s.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have replied, there are plenty of loudspeakers with digital input options. I am sure there are suitable option available, which will match Your price range and preference of digital output type.

Just Google "_location_preference_ loudspeaker with _digital_input preference_ IN" and you should find plenty of options.

(eg. Desktop loudspeaker with SPDIF IN)

However, in order to speaker to work, there must be a Digital-to-Analog conversion, sooner or later. There is no such thing as Digital amp and no one expects to listen "0"'s and "1"'s directly, would you agree? :)